# FRC Java Mecanum Drive

Tags: java, robotics

I am the programmer for my FRC Team 4468 and we are using mecanum wheels this year. We are trying to control the robot with two joysticks, one for moving in a direction (mecStick), and another for rotation (rotStick) using this line of code.

```
 myDrive.mecanumDrive_Cartesian(mecStick.getX(), mecStick.getX(), rotStick.getY(), 0);
```

The robot will move in the Y direction (fowards, backwards), and will rotate but won't move in the X axis. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please.

Thanks :-)

```
public class RobotTemplate extends SimpleRobot {

RobotDrive myDrive = new RobotDrive(1,2,3,4);
Joystick mecStick = new Joystick(1);
Joystick rotStick = new Joystick(2);



public void robotInit() {

}


public void autonomous() {

}

public void operatorControl() {

    //myDrive.setSafetyEnabled(true);

    myDrive.mecanumDrive_Cartesian(mecStick.getX(), mecStick.getX(), rotStick.getY(), 0);

    Timer.delay(0.01);


   }

}
```

Comment: I have no answer but try ask on Chiefdelphi instead. They have all about FRC and stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you pass `mecStick.getX()` twice, one should probably be `mecStick.getY()`. I'm not familiar with the RobotDrive class, so I'm not sure which should be switched. The WPILib Javadoc is your friend, you can find a copy hosted by team 2168 at http://team2168.org/javadoc/. Look for RobotDrive on the left bottom list, and check there.

Best of luck from 1902, Exploding Bacon!